# Customizing y-axis in Highchart.js (stockchart)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to customize the **y-axis** of my highchart so that every series will start from 100% and not as it is by default from 0% ?

Here is an example for better understanding:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Here is the js code for showing the percentages in the y-axis:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },
```

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to make your chart display data from 100% to 0% (where the yAxis starts at 100%) or are your data points all more than / equal to 100%?

Comment: Yes, my data points are all more than 100%. The spectrum goes from 100% to 180%

Comment: How about setting [min](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.min) value as 100 on yAxis?

Comment: yAxis: {
             min: 100,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
             
            },

Comment: Unfortunately with this settings no more series will be rendered.

Comment: Sorry for not using the code-tag in my previous post.

Answer (score 1):

To simply reverse the y-axis, you could use

```
 yAxis: {
     reversed: true,
 },
```

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed

If you're instead trying to display data starting from 100% and upwards, you could set the minimum value to be 100, like this:

```
 yAxis: {
     min: 100
 },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.min